# Stripe webhook cannot access Express request raw body

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, webhooks

I just copied the code in the official Stripe Docs about basic webhook usage, but it keeps throwing me the same error. The only thing you can see I changed is that instead of using express.json() middleware I used rawBody.json(), and I did it because in the docs it says "If you are using Express v4 - v4.16 you need to use body-parser, not express, to retrieve the request body". The code for replication can be found in the docs, but I attach it here just in case I miss something. The error is a 400 Bad request and the description is: "Webhook Error: Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer"

```
dotenv.config()

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

const app = express()

app.use(morgan("dev"))

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN,
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
)

app.post("/webhook", bodyParser.json(), (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"]

  let event

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      payload,
      sig,
      process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    )

    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      console.log("Session completed successfully")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
  }

  response.status(200).end()
})

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }))

//Rest of endpoints
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `express.raw({ type: 'application/json' })`.

```
const express = require('express');

app.post("/webhook", express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"]

  let event

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      payload,
      sig,
      process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    )

    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      console.log("Session completed successfully")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
  }

  response.status(200).end()
})
```

Here is a [github](https://github.com/Dinuda/-Stripe-Webhook-and-Checkout-Session-Example/blob/main/index.js) example on using webhooks on stripe

Comment: Alright, that was it! Thank you so much for the contribution

Comment: Pleasure (: if you find this helpful you could mark this answer as correct and upvote  so that others would find it as the answer that helped your question